# training_updates = Adam(lr=lrD, beta_1=0.5).get_updates(weightsD,[],loss_D) TypeError: get_updates() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, keras

I am getting this error when I try to run the code "https://github.com/b01902041/Deep-Virtual-Try-on-with-Clothes-Transform" in this link.

Error: "training_updates = Adam(lr=lrD, beta_1=0.5).get_updates(weightsD,[],loss_D)
TypeError: get_updates() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given"

This happens when I'm trying to run the "CAGAN.py" code "https://github.com/b01902041/Deep-Virtual-Try-on-with-Clothes-Transform" in this link.

I tried this code in python versions 3.7,3.8,3.9,3.10.
I'm using Tensorflow version 2.11.0.

Please help me in resolving this error.

Comment: Welcome. Questions on this site need to be self-contained, meaning that all relevant information (relevant code, full error traceback messages, etc.) needs to be posted here in text format. Do not post links to external locations of source code. If the script you are trying to run is long, you'll need to post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Also, you should check the repo's issues page to see if this problem has been raised there, and consider opening an issue and asking for assistance.